# R ggplot2 arrowheads with geom_text

Tags: r, ggplot2, text

I use geom_text to plot some text. A text example would be:

```
a -> 7.0
```

However, instead of using "->" as an arrowhead I would like to use an arrowhead symbole.

I found the package plotmath to be used with ggplot to plot symboles.

I am not sure if it wouldn't be easier to plot the text separated from the actual symbol and align them using different coordinates that are close together so that once plotted it looks like a single string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to pass it as an expression and use the `parse=TRUE` option for `geom_text`. The `geom_text` documentation should provide you with enough to get going:

Plotmath with `geom_text`: [link](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Plotmath).